# issue in user Quota creation

Tags: linux, disk, quota

I am trying to create a users quota in RHEL-7 with xfs file system. But I am not able do it. 
The procedure that I followed is as below :-

1) edit `/etc/fstab/`

> /dev/mapper/rhel-root  /   xfs  defaults,usrquota,grpquota        0 0
>   UUID=58c22d1f-85ca-4fb9-8d40-4cfbaaf0d7ca /boot  xfs defaults        0 0

2) Then 
`mount -vo remount /`

> mount: /dev/mapper/rhel-root mounted on /.

3) reboot too

and then checked if quota feature is enabled or not , and fount it is not enabled.

```
 # mount | grep 'root'
```

> /dev/mapper/rhel-root on / type xfs   (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

Can you tell me its cause and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

xfs file system manages quota differently from other fs. And you need to activate flag rootflags=quota in the /etc/default/grub.

In detail: 
edit /etc/default/grub, adding or editing  the value

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rootflags=quota"
```

run update-grub and performs reboot. Quota should be activated. This process may be slightly different depending on the distro.

Comment: you can also read **man xfs-quota**

Comment: Is there any way I can do changes without reboot , as per your instruction it require reboot as I am doing changes in grub file.

Comment: No, you have to reboot. I think is the only way...